# Changing breakpoint statement border color

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, themes

I can't for the life of me find the name of the text string that corresponds to the border of the breakpoint statement that turns visible as soon as you highlight that row. I've tried with search strings such as "breakpoint" and "highlight" in the Theme Editor but haven't been successful yet.

I want to change the color of this border:

[image]

Actually I want to remove it completely, as I find it pretty annoying (make the color transparent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to change the border of the selected text when there's a breakpoint you should be able to do that on `Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors>Show settings for: Text Editor`, and then scroll down and change the value of `Breakpoint-Selected`, but it doesn't change anything. Probably its a bug.

Comment: You're right. It doesn't seem to have any effect. How strange is that! But thanks for spotting this.

Comment: Just restart VS it will change. @silkfire

Comment: @silkfire yeah look at this http://i.stack.imgur.com/3kp4n.png. Btw I tried to set background to none, it works either.

Comment: @Berkay Setting it to transparent didn't work, but setting it the same color worked. It's a bit unexpected though, the color of the border is slightly lighter than the box itself.

Comment: @Berkay It's the border color I'm interested in - nothing else.